# Can I give function pointer to template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can I do something like this?

```
template<function_pointer_type pointer_name> struct structure1{
   //here I call pointer_name(0)
};

void* function1 = [&](int a) {
   return a * a;
}
structure1<function1> b;
```

I tried but it never compiled.

Comment: @NickyC suppose it doesn't compile because I used wrong one. I guess function_pointer_type is decltype(function1). Could you tell how it should looks like?

Comment: Could that be because `function1` isn't a function pointer?

Comment: I'm really new in function pointers. Could you tell me please how it should looks like?

Comment: One day we'll have [constexpr lambdas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf) and then you may get your wish.

Comment: I suggest, don't use function pointer at all.

Comment: What can I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

So, what's wrong with the code?

1. `function1` is not constant expression so it cannot be used as template argument.
2. The lambda is not convertible to function pointer because it has a non-empty capture list.

Instead of function pointer, I suggest using a template parameter of function object, or `std::function`.

Function object:

```
template <class FunctionObject>
class A
{
private:
    FunctionObject fun;

public:
    A(FunctionObject f) : fun(f) {}

    void f() { cout << fun(5) << endl; }
};

template <class FunctionObject>
A<FunctionObject> make_A(FunctionObject f)
{
    return A<FunctionObject>(f);
}
```

`std::function`:

```
template <class FunctionType>
struct B
{
    std::function<FunctionType> fun;
};
```

The usage:

```
void usage()
{
    auto a = make_A([](int a) {return a*a; });
    a.f();

    B<int(int)> b;
    b.fun = [&](int a) {return a*a; };
    cout << b.fun(10) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this as absolutely similar to your original question as possible (using a lambda and a templated structure and so on):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename F>
struct structure1 {
    structure1(F x) : f(x) {}
    int operator() (int a) { return f(a); };
    F f;
};

int(*function1)(int) = [&](int a) {
    return a * a;
};

int main() {
    structure1< int(*)(int) > x(function1);
    std::cout << x(4) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled and tested this with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`